# Vue Router meta fields

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

I was wondering if its possible to define custom properties when passing routes to VueRouter. For example for the majority of routes in my app I would like to define a route such as the following where I can pass a component to an optional property "menu":

```
{ path: "/section-stack", component: SectionStack, menu: SectionMenu }
```

A read of the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html) points towards using the meta field for this but this doesn't achieve what I want and results in more verbose routes. Looking into the code, each route passed to VueRouter is of type RouteConfig. Is it possible to modify my VueRouter so that it can be passed routes of a different type? I.e. of type RouteConfig with additional properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `meta` is still the way to go. I once created a breadcrumb with it. My route looked like this:

```js
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: require('./routes/Home.vue'),
      meta: {
        history: [],
      },
    },
    {
      path: '/projects',
      name: 'projects',
      component: () => System.import('./routes/Projects.vue'),
      meta: {
        history: ['home'],
      },
    },
    {
      path: '/project/:token',
      name: 'project',
      component: () => System.import('./routes/project/Overview.vue'),
      meta: {
        text: (vue) => vue.projects[vue.$route.params.token] || vue.$route.params.token,
        to: { name: 'project', params: { token: (vue) => vue.$route.params.token } } ,
        history: ['home', 'projects'],
    }
  ]
```

In my vue-component I could access the meta by watching `$route` and while loading the component by iterating through the `$router` object like this:

```js
export default {
    beforeMount() {
      this.allRoutes = {};
      this.$router.options.routes.forEach(route => {
          if (route.name) {
            let text = (route.meta && route.meta.text) || route.name;
            this.$set(this.allRoutes, route.name, {
                text: text,
                to: (route.meta && route.meta.to) || { name: route.name }
              }
            );
          }
        }
      );
    },
    data() {
      return {
        allRoutes: {},
        currentList: [],
      };
    },
    watch: {
      '$route'(to, from) {
        this.currentList = ((to.meta && to.meta.history).slice(0) || []);
        this.currentList.push(to.name);
      }
    },
  }
```

Especially the `forEach` in `beforeMount` could be a solution to build a menu, that f.e. is based on roles that are defined in the meta-object.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've upvoted you but haven't accepted your answer as it's not what I'm looking for.  A further reason that I'd like to use a a specific property of type Component is that it would be type safe where as meta accepts any type.

Comment: If you want `meta` to be type-safe in your application, you could define a custom app-specific `RouteConfig` that defines a specific type for your the fields that you want to define in the `meta` property.

For example:

import { RouteConfig } from 'vue-router'

...

export type MyAppRouteConfig = Omit<RouteConfig, 'meta'> & {
  meta: {
    property1: string,
    property2: number,
    ...
  }
}

The downside of that is you have to reference this type throughout your application rather than importing the `RouteConfig` from `vue-router` directly

Sorry formatting is messed up

Answer (score 0):

To complement my comment in the first answer (formatting not supported in comments) and build off of Markus Madeja's answer, if you want the `meta` property to be type-safe, you could define your own custom type extending `RouteConfig`:

```js
import { RouteConfig } from 'vue-router'
...
export type MyAppRouteConfig = Omit<RouteConfig, 'meta'> & {
  meta: {
    property1: string,
    property2: number,
    ...
  }
}
```